# How to solve HT Tracker error log problem?

Tags: mongodb, alfresco-webscripts, best-fit

I am making a copy of a website by using HT tracker but aftersome of processing it is showing error log, Is anybody know how can i solve it. And I am not a well cooder so please suggest me the easy method.

[image: THis is the screenshot of HT Tracker]
I am search on Google but could not found the better method.